# Something wrong when i want connect to API Local Server

Tags: java, android

why i cannot connect to localhost server from my android Apps... i have setup my laravel for make API... and Set host using Ipv4 like 192.168.x.x and set using php artisan serve --host=192.168.x.x and i have set endpoint at my android apps using that host... and i have using same Wifi with my laptop.. but i cannot connect to my local server why like that ? any idea ? but when i want check my connection to server using browser i can connect.

i have turn off my firewall, connect to server using browser, and using same IP. and it work but when i want to open my apps i cannot open. cannot connect to server

```
//*********** API Base URL ********//


public static final String ECOMMERCE_IMAGE_URL = "http://192.168.x.x/";
public static final String ECOMMERCE_URL = "http://192.168.x.x/";

public static final String ECOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY = "ffc8e6f6153078631196ecb74d";
public static final String ECOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET = "4c5b729a1530786311a40280c1";
```

cannot connect to server.

Comment: are your phone well connected  to the same network ?

Comment: check your IP address static one or dynamic one

Comment: yes i have use same WIfi connection but cannot work when use my localhost laptop